# How to input into an array

Tags: c, command-line, user-input

```
main(int c,char **args){
int i
char input[100];
bzero(input,100);
for(i=1;i<c;i++)
  {
    input=strcat(input,args);
    input=strcat(input," ");
  }

}
```

i have included the string.h header file....

I want the input i enter in the command line to be stored in the input array.
could anyone please correct my code..
Thank you.

Comment: it crashes at the latest, if sum of argv-lens >= 100 (sizeof input); bzero is not C89 or C99

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two fatal problems - the first is that you need to access the `args[i]` member of the argument array, and the second is that you can't assign directly to the `input` variable, since it's an array.

In addition:

- You should check that there is sufficient room in the `input` array;
- It's good style to explicitly return a value from `main()`;
- Whitespace is cheap, use it.

Here's what it looks like with those issues fixed:

```
int main(int c, char **args)
{
    int i;
    char input[100];

    bzero(input, 100);

    for(i = 1; i < c; i++)
    {
        if (strlen(input) + strlen(args[i]) + 2 <= 100)
        {
            strcat(input, args[i]);
            strcat(input, " ");
        }
    }

    puts(input);

    return 0;
}
```

(I also included the `puts()` line so that you can see what ends up in `input`).

Comment: thnx a lot...but in that If condition why did you put +2 ?

Comment: 1 for the `" "` and 1 for the nul terminator.

Answer (score 0):

You're close - try `strcat(input, args[i])`.

Answer (score 0):

"char** args" is already an array of strings. This is the same thing as saying "char* args[]".

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem.

```
  main(int c,char **args){
    int i
    char input[100];
    bzero(input,100);
    for(i=1;i<c;i++)
      {
        strcat(input,args[i]);
        strcat(input," ");
      }
    }
```

Comment: it crashes, if sum of argv-lens >= 100 (sizeof input);
bzero is not C89 or C99

Answer (score 0):

**int c** is the number of arguments plus name of the file that is value of c is integer and given as (number of arguments passed+1)

**char **args** contain the pointers which points to the arguments you are passing.

you need to change 7 th line of your program as follow;

input=strcat(input,args[i]);

Answer (score 0):

```
main(int c, char **args)
{
  while( c-- )
    printf(" %s",*args++);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not want to limit your program to 100 chars input. You can use [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/) to dynamically extend the size of the array *input*.

And avoid using *bzero*, instead use *memset* that is part of the standard. Even though you could omit that line.

```
int main(int c, char **args) {
int i;
int limit = 100;
char *input = calloc(limit,sizeof(limit));

memset(input,0, limit * sizeof(char)); // No need but better than bzero.
for (i=0;i<c;i++) {
    if (strlen(input) + strlen(args[i]) + 2 > limit) { //avoiding input overflow.
       limit = strlen(input) + strlen(args[i]) + 2;
       input = realloc(input,limit);
    }
    strcat(input,args[i]);
    strcat(input," ");
}
puts(input);
free(input);
return 0;
```

}